# Python Google cloud API request location error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to make API request woth python to googlw cloud. The target is to read data from cloud storage and write it to bigquery.

Unfortunately I get the following error when trying to do it.”cannot write to destination us as reading from EU.”

Both the cloud storage and bigquery are in EU location so I cant figure out the reason for this error.
Hi, Here is the code im using: imgur.com/a/DTj0Uhp and the error im getting when running the script is "google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US Location: US" –

I have check google settings and cannot find the reason why the error says Im trying to write to US location.

Comment: Hello, would you kindly post some code snippets that in your opinion could be representative of the issue at hand? Can you also share the screenshots of the commands (inputs/outputs) to identify the various configurations that may lead to the issue. Thank you

Comment: also, which API is actually returning the error? BQ? What exact endpoint? Have you tried looking at the relevant documentation to see if the location can/must be set in your API call?

Comment: Hi, Here is the code im using: https://imgur.com/a/DTj0Uhp and the error im getting when running the script is "google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US

Location: US"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Matti! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Just edit your question to add the code contained in your image :)